# How can i make bold a single character in the lable without using UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a UILabel which contains textvalue and i want to bold a particular character in that whole string so please let me inform is it possible? and yes then please give me some example it really important for me.Please help me.

Comment: may be more then one label because it is in tableview and if you know for single even that also let me say how it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible as single-line label if you create a custom UIView subclass, and implement the `-drawRect:` like this:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   NSString* stringBefore;
   NSString* boldPart;
   NSString* stringAfter;
   UIFont* normalFont;
   UIFont* boldFont;
   ...
   CGSize sizeBefore = [stringBefore drawAtPoint:CGPointZero withFont:normalFont];
   CGSize sizeBold = [boldPart drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sizeBefore.width, 0) withFont:boldFont];
   [stringAfter drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sizeBefore.width+sizeBold.width, 0) withFont:normalFont];
}
```

Comment: Ya man!i think it will work,great job but still i want some easier way if possible!.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can be done in 3.2 (and higher) with NSAttributedString.  But not in the iPhone as it exists today.

Comment: ok but can you give me some code that can do particular character bold.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any offhand - you'll have to look for NSAttributedString examples.